# Sort post meta data using meta_key?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to get the post, meta datas on table wp_postmeta. I need to get the post id, meta keys and meta value by using the meta_key and post id. The meta key stored is date. eg,. 2014-01-02, 2014-02-03, I have to query them based on the year or month.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'calendar_holiday',
        'ID' => $id; 
    'meta_query' => array(

        array(
            'key' => ,
            'value' => ,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),

    )
);


$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I'm not sure what to put on key and value.. any idea?? thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
  //  'orderby'    =>  'meta_value_num', // it's a numeric value

$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'post_type' => 'calendar_holiday',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'over-make',
            'value' => 'Doral',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )

 );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```